# text box is giving error with differnt bar codes

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, barcode

i am using a barcode reader. when i place the cursor on the textbox1 and scan the barcode of an item it is copied in the textbox1. when other items barcodes are scanned i usually get error like **"Invalid column name 'C902SA20K'."** it only accepts the first one barcode which was entered in the textbox for the first time. when the barcode is entered in different textboxes other than the textbox1 only the first letter or alphabet is scanned and provides with the error **"The conversion of the nvarchar value '8736900083240' overflowed an int column."**

how can i make it accept all the barcodes.

Comment: Kindly edit the question and try to elaborate, I read it thrice but cannot understand your problem

Comment: No one can help you. Please show some code where you are getting error. Use break points to debug.

Comment: Are you using the barcode(s) to seek something in a database? How are you separating/parsing the values that arrive?

Comment: @sq33G....i am using the barcode which are by the company...i am not generating my own barcodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the column or field that gets the value `8736900083240`, is either `int` or is `cast to int`. This value is too big to be stored in an int field. An `int32` field can store a max of `2147483647` and an `unsigned int32` can store a max of `4294967295`. You may like to use a `long` or a `suitably sized data type` for 8736900083240 value.

Comment: actually some barcode contains alphabets so in datbase i have used nvarchar for it but still it gives the error.